# Where should i start learning about networking

Tags: networking, proxy, p2p

I've software engg. degree so i know some stuff about how networks and routers and IP addressing work in general. But i need to learn specifics.
The question in mind is how is proxy working on a computer?
For example i have proxy server in my workplace, i need to put some proxy in Internet settings and wolah my browser would work. But at same time i can't ping ip's and for example i won't be able to play my game (COD4) using server address because i don't know how connecting to some server via game works and at same time browser does it seamlessly. Also i'm interested in development of softwares that can direct my traffic. Many softwares are on github that are proxy servers and i can run those but i have no idea what actual work they perform and how are they useful and how can i learn and code to use that type of code. And torrents..!! how does torrent works and how is it blocked etc. Just need some direction that's all. :)

Comment: PS: i'm not in dire need to play games in my workplace just that i'm curious how can i dig in and maybe be more creative. i had idea of creating such a local server of my game (COD4) that could work in local area but not on same router. but i have no idea how would my computer and other computers will direct traffic to eachother etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking for some CISCO ICND1 material. It is well explained and covers the basics of networking.